# Issue migrating users to new Firebase database with hash-algo

Tags: firebase, hash, firebase-cli

Migrating users to new firebase database.

1. Export to json
2. Import to new database as following:

> firebase auth:import users.json --hash-algo=SCRYPT --rounds=8
>   --mem-cost=14 --hash-key=longstringofchars --salt-separator=longstringofchars --project project-123

Getting the following error:

> error: unknown option '--hash-algo'

Comment: That's weird I'm trying the same thing, getting the same error but when I make `firebase auth:import --help` I'm getting

```
Usage: firebase auth:import [options] [dataFile]

import users into your Firebase project from a data file(.csv or .json)

Options:
  --hash-algo <hashAlgo>               specify the hash algorithm used in password for these accounts
```

Comment: @EzeTeja where did you copy the commands from? First, paste the command into a notepad to clear formatting. I think that was my issue at the time.

Comment: First I tried from the docs, then I build the command myself using --help

`firebase auth:import %ACCOUNTS_FILE% --hash-algo=SCRYPT --hash-key=%HASH_KEY% --salt-separator=%SALT_SEPARATOR% --rounds=%ROUNDS% --mem-cost=%MEM_COST% --token %FIREBASE_TOKEN%`